# How to put iPhone's screen onto mac in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa

I watched a tutorial, what that guy did on his iPhone, appeared in Xcode simultaneously, and just like in a simulator. How to do that? THX.

Comment: Could you post the link to this tutorial?

Comment: I'm trying, it's too long, I almost forgot where that part is...

Comment: If i have to guess you can have Airserver (If airplay is not available on your mac) and have the Mirroring option from the iPhone. then you can have your iphone on your mac

Comment: @Manu Oh, that's another solution. Thanks a lot. But I still wondering how to achieve that in Xcode, I happen to know that u need to join the iPhone Develop Program at least(for u to test your app on your iPhone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities, depending on what *exactly* you saw in the tutorial.

### Live video

If the video was live, there are two things he could have been doing:

#### Airserver, etc. (blue bar)

He could have been using an AirPlay Mirroring server app to use Airplay Mirroring on the iPhone to show his screen directly onto the Mac's screen. This is the most **probable** method.

#### Simulator (no blue bar)

He could have actually been using the simulator, unless he specifically said he was using a device. There are apps you can use to make your mouse look like a finger on the simulator's display. Slightly unlikely.

### Still pictures

This is the more unlikely version of the two, and would mean that all you could see was individual still pictures of the app running on the device.

In the Xcode organizer, you can go to the screenshots tab for a device and take a screenshot of the current display of the device. Highly unlikely.

Comment: I can still remember that there is no blue bar, and a carrier's name is at the upper-left corner. And all the operations he did and all the apps he installed really show that it is a real phone, not pictures or a simulator. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 31):

Open QuickTime Player,

```
File>New Movie Recording
```

Besides Record button(on the Quick Time Player), there is down arrow.

Click on down arrow and select iPhone

Comment: This is the simplest way of sharing and recording your iOS device screen on a Mac. No additional software required, just standard out-of-the-box QuickTime.

Comment: My down air just shows Quality High/Maximum.  No iPhone option.

Comment: Somehow, the quick player didn't have option to display AppleWatch screen...

Comment: When I do that, Xcode loses the connection to the debugged app on the iPhone :(

Comment: This is (no longer) true. You can record from your iPhone's camera, but not its screen.

Comment: It still works.  I just did it today on Ventura 13.3.1.

Comment: Yes but in Sonoma it's not working anymore. :'( It shows the camera view now.